# US visa application from UK, DS-160 form, UK not found?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, uk-residents

I was trying to apply for an American Visa from UK. However, when I was intending to fill in the DS-160 form [here](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/). I can not find the country of United Kingdom (or Britain and Great Britain)!

Can you test it? I believe I have carefully checked the entire drop down menu list and I did not find London. I am confused.

The drop down menu:
[image]

Comment: Oh the joys of having a country which is part of another country :P

Comment: Yeah, I hate the fact that whenever I use a drop-down list to choose the country I live in, I have to guess whether the form designer thinks I live in the United Kingdom, Great Britain, Britain or England.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some websites still have Yugoslavia, so you are lucky that you have to select a country that still exists

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's there, under *England, London*.

[image: DS-160]

Comment: The USA is already preparing for the eventual break-up of the UK :D

Comment: "ENGLAND" is indeed unusual...

Comment: @zlin I was looking at a Canadian site recently, and they had the same.

Comment: I guess they don't want people getting confused about London, Ontario or London, Texas (or several other Londons in the USA).

Comment: @alephzero Except that all the Canadian cities are listed in the style of "Canada, London", not "Ontario, London". Subnational entities don't seem to be used for any other country.

Comment: @Pharap Look at the actual site. Every single city is labelled as "Country, City". It is not because people might confuse Paris, France with Paris, Texas in the context of visa applications. It is because people who are in France want to apply for a visa and to see all the options of places in France where they can apply for a visa grouped together. An alternative interface would be to first ask the country and then display a list of cities (corresponding to embassies and consulates) within that country.

Comment: I had exactly the same question. Thank you for solving this!